# Change the Datatype of a Column in the entire Database - MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am new to MySQL. I have designed few tables with Char datatype. Now I want to change all the char datatype columns to Varchar with respective size mentioned in Char.

```
For example.
Existing - Phone Char(10) 
Expected - Phone Varchar(10)
```

There are around 50 Plus tables. I know how to alter the datatype for each and every table and column but is there any better way to change the datatype in a single shot.

Comment: Try this query `ALTER TABLE db.table
MODIFY COLUMN Phone VARCHAR(100);`

Comment: Short answer is that you can't change datatype for some columns, based on the columns datatype, in all tables without specifying table names and column names.
I wouldn't even bother trying to write a script to figure that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't write a script to do the job, write a script that writes a script to do the job!

You want a bunch of ALTER TABLE statements:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; -- Bumps the limit of 1028
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
        'ALTER TABLE `',
        table_name,
        '` MODIFY COLUMN `',
        column_name,
        '` VARCHAR(',
        character_maximum_length,
        ')'
    )
SEPARATOR ';\n') your_alter_statements
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'concrete'
AND data_type = 'char';
```

This'll result in:

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` MODIFY COLUMN `col1` VARCHAR(10);
ALTER TABLE `table1` MODIFY COLUMN `col2` VARCHAR(10);
ALTER TABLE `table2` MODIFY COLUMN `col1` VARCHAR(10);
ALTER TABLE `table3` MODIFY COLUMN `col1` VARCHAR(10);
ALTER TABLE `table3` MODIFY COLUMN `col2` VARCHAR(10);
```

Run that and you can go home early!

UPDATE: Stopped the truncation by adding `group_concat_max_len`. Made the length dynamic based on the columns length.

Comment: I prepared an SQL myself which is somewhat similar to your solution. Anyhow thanks for your help.

Comment: I have given you an example as char(10) but the size differs for each and every table.

Comment: Ah, so you want to keep the size. So if it's CHAR(99), make it VARCHAR(99)?

Comment: Thank you Adrian Lynch. Its time to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL only one liner solution:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ',TABLE_NAME, ' MODIFY COLUMN ',COLUMN_NAME, CONCAT(' VARCHAR(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ');')
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where DATA_TYPE = 'char' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='concrete'
```

Above query will return all `ALTER TABLE` statements, example shown below:

```
ALTER TABLE     tablename1   MODIFY COLUMN  col_name1    VARCHAR(17);
ALTER TABLE     tablename2   MODIFY COLUMN  col_name2    VARCHAR(17);
ALTER TABLE     tablename3   MODIFY COLUMN  col_name3    VARCHAR(60);
```

Copy the resulting rows and execute, so you can go home even more early.

Additionally, below is PHP/MySQL solution:

```
// Initialise Connection
define('DB_HOST', 'HOST_NAME_HERE');
define('DB_NAME', 'DB_NAME_HERE');
define('DB_USER_NAME', 'DB_USER_NAME_HERE');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'DB_PASSWORD_HERE');

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER_NAME, DB_PASSWORD, [
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
]);

// Get a list of CHAR columns
$sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where DATA_TYPE = 'char' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='" . DB_NAME . "'";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Change CHAR to VARCHAR
foreach ($data as $rec) {
    $ddq = 'ALTER TABLE ' . $rec['TABLE_NAME'] . ' CHANGE ' . $rec['COLUMN_NAME'] . ' ' . $rec['COLUMN_NAME'] . ' VARCHAR(' .
           $rec['CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH'] . ') ' . ($rec['IS_NULLABLE'] == 'YES' ? 'NULL' : 'NOT NULL') . (isset($rec['COLUMN_DEFAULT']) ? " DEFAULT '{$rec['COLUMN_DEFAULT']}'" : '');
    $pdo->query($ddq);
}
```

Comment: Its purely from MySQL Database end

Comment: @NewUser, only If you have a PHP environment with MySQL, you can run above script

Comment: @NewUser, udpated my answer, added mysql only

Comment: Thanks Aamir. I already selected Adrian answer but I can vote up.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the web, I got the answer and changed the datatype using this query.

```
select 
concat('ALTER TABLE ', table_name,' MODIFY COLUMN ', column_name,' ', REPLACE (column_type, 'char', 'varchar'),';')
from information_schema.columns
where 
data_type='char' 
and table_schema='DBName';
```

Comment: My script is better. You end up with new lines for each statement, the table and column names get escaped, when you copy the result each statement isn't wrapped in single quotes (copying from Workbench does that) and the REPLACE in yours is redundant.

Comment: @AdrianLynch, SQL does not require new lines for each statement, but a semicolon is enough

Answer (score 0):

If your field is PK ('id' smallint unsigned for example) and some other tables have constraints with foreign keys for this PK use this query.

note: for modern mysql servers remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from Variables -> sql mode, by default it contains:

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Then insert and execute this query:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 10000;
SET @database_name = "database1";
SET @table_name = "table1";
SET @change = "mediumint unsigned";
SELECT DISTINCT 
       `table_name`,
       `column_name`,
       `constraint_name`,
       `referenced_table_name`,
       `referenced_column_name`,
       CONCAT(
           GROUP_CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `',table_name,'` DROP FOREIGN KEY `',constraint_name, '`' SEPARATOR ';'),
           ';',
           GROUP_CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `',table_name,'` CHANGE `',column_name,'` `',column_name,'` ',@change SEPARATOR ';'),
           ';',
           CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `',@table_name,'` CHANGE `',referenced_column_name,'` `',referenced_column_name,'` ',@change, ' NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT'),
           ';',
           GROUP_CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `',table_name,'` ADD CONSTRAINT `',constraint_name,'` FOREIGN KEY(',column_name,') REFERENCES ',referenced_table_name,'(',referenced_column_name,')' SEPARATOR ';'), 
           ';'
       ) AS query
FROM   `information_schema`.`key_column_usage`
WHERE  `referenced_table_name` IS NOT NULL
   AND `referenced_column_name` IS NOT NULL
   AND `constraint_schema` = @database_name
   AND `referenced_table_name` = @table_name
GROUP BY `referenced_table_name`;
```

note: check EXTRA OPTIONS to show full text for fields in result.
Then copy and execute all generated queries.
Restore ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in Variables.

Enjoy!